# Is there a way to install a kernel module on an AKS node in Azure Kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, configmap, daemonset

I am trying to install the nfs-kernel-server package on all nodes in my AKS cluster. The kernel module for NFS is not installed by default in AKS Ubuntu 16.04. I am following the guide here: https://medium.com/@patnaikshekhar/initialize-your-aks-nodes-with-daemonsets-679fa81fd20e.

my daemonset:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: installer
  namespace: node-installer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      job: installer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        job: installer
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - image: patnaikshekhar/node-installer:1.3
        name: installer
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: install-script
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: host-mount
          mountPath: /host
      volumes:
      - name: install-script
        configMap:
          name: sample-installer-config
      - name: host-mount
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/install
```

and this is my configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-installer-config
  namespace: node-installer
data:
  install.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    # Update and install packages
    apt-get update
    apt-get install nfs-kernel-server -y
```

Letting the pods build and complete (x3), when I inspect their logs, only the first pod's logs show the package installed on the node. The rest of the pods have no log at all. Is there a way to reliably accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to accomplish this is with a daemonset and configmap, with a pod execution policy of privileged and a host path mount. That way the container can install the required packages onto the host node, and the daemonset will apply the configuration to all new nodes on the cluster.